# Mersenne prime is a pseudoprime

Tags: prime-numbers

Suppose $M_p=2^p-1$, where $p$ is a prime, is composite.

Work:
Then $M_p = ab$ for positive integers $1 < a,b < M_p$.

I want to show

$2^{ab}=k2^{2^p-1}+2$

---> $2^{2^p-1}-2=k2^{2^p-1}$

---> $2^{2^p-1} \mid 2^{2^p-1}-2$

---> $2^{2^p-1} \equiv 2 \pmod {2^p-1}$

May I ask for help on filling my missing steps? I'm not getting this, I'm sorry. :(

Answer (score 1):

The first statement is false: $2^{2^p-1}$ and $k 2^{2^p-1}$ are divisible by $4$, for example, but $2$ isn't.  So I hope that's **not** what you want to show.

Comment: I want to show the very last statement in my question post. That is the definition of $2^p-1$ being pseudoprime (w.r.t base $2$). Also, I must remark that your "answer" reads more like a comment.

Comment: So why are you trying to get $2^{2^p-1}$, rather than $2^p-1$, to divide $2^{2^p-1} - 2$?